# How can I use single file vue component with symfony 4?

Tags: symfony, vue.js, vuejs2, webpack-encore

What I want to do is:
1) in app.js to be able to use

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Time from './vue/components/Time'

Vue.component('vue-time', {
    template: '<span class="foo bar">Hi</span>'
})

new Vue({
    el: 'header',
    components: { Time }
})
```

2) in Time.vue:

```
<template>
    <div>current time</div>
</template>

<script>
    module.exports = {

    }
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Is this possible? All is implemented using encore-webpack and symfony4.
Thanks.

Comment: There's no reason that this shouldn't work. Symfony4 or not, it's all about webpack transpiling the assets correctly for you.

Comment: Hi, what if I want to load component from a Vue file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in **app.js** registered 2 components:

1. **Time** - registered localy
2. **vue-time** - registered global

if you want register **Time** global add in **app.js** this:

*do not use name `Time` https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/HTML/Element/time

```
Vue.component(`Time`, Time)
```

in **app.js** delete this:

```
components: { Time }
```

then use tag `<time></time>` anywhere in your application

Comment: Hi, it seems that the problem was time tag of which I did not know. Strange.